# VS2013 handler has a bad module managedpipelinehandler in its module list

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have an `ASP.NET` application that I can debug correctly with `Visual Studio 2012` but, when I try to debug it with `Visual Studio 2013`, I have the following error message:

```
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "`xxx`" has a bad module "`ManagedPipelineHandler`" in its module list.
```

Does anyone knows what could be different between **VS 2012** and **VS 2013** on this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case handler was in two places:

```
<system.web>
...
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="ApplicArt.Extranet2.Controller.FrontController, ApplicArt.Extranet2.Web.UI" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  ...
  <add name="FrontController" verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="ApplicArt.Extranet2.Controller.FrontController, ApplicArt.Extranet2.Web.UI"/>
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And when I removed my handler from [system.webServer] section my problem disappeared.